# Slow COUNT(*) with JSON_SEARCH

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table that stores tags in the JSON format for each page. Current table has about 1,000,000 records. 
When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alltags WHERE tagtype = 'pages' AND JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'Hampden') IS NOT NULL;
```

the query takes about 20 seconds

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    23500 |
+----------+
1 row in set (19.20 sec)
```

The query is slow regardless if I use InnoDB or MyISAM engine.
I got indexes for tagtype, tags and tagtype with tags columns. I need the exact number of results for pagination. Is there a way I can speed up the SELECT COUNT query? Selecting actual data is pretty instant.

```
SELECT id FROM alltags WHERE tagtype = 'pages' AND JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'Hampden') IS NOT NULL LIMIT 0,10;

+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 5072 |
| 5075 |
| 5078 |
| 5081 |
| 5084 |
| 5087 |
| 5090 |
| 5093 |
| 5096 |
| 5099 |
+------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

These are the indexes

```
SHOW INDEX FROM alltags;

+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| alltags |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |      896649 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alltags |          1 | tagtype   |            1 | tagtype     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alltags |          1 | keyword   |            1 | keyword     | A         |          33 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alltags |          1 | tags      |            1 | tags        | A         |       89665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

EXPLAIN results:

Select data

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM alltags WHERE tagtype = 'pages' AND JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'Hampden') IS NOT NULL;

+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alltags | NULL       | ref  | tagtype       | tagtype | 7       | const | 892372 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Select count

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alltags WHERE tagtype = 'pages' AND JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'Hampden') IS NOT NULL;

+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alltags | NULL       | ref  | tagtype       | tagtype | 7       | const | 892372 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It's not `COUNT` that is slow, but `JSON_SEARCH`

Comment: what are the indexes on the table?

Comment: @zerkms Why is retrieving the actual data is really fast then?

Comment: @Andrew I edited the post to show the indexes

Comment: Can you add the result of an `explain ...count_query...` and `explain ...actual data query without the LIMIT` please

Comment: @JohnBaker how do you know it's fast? You only run the similar query with `LIMIT 0, 10`. No wondering scanning 10 rows is faster than scanning 23.5k rows.

Comment: It determines how the indexes are used on both queries, therefore you will be able to change or create appropriated indexes based on the explain result.

Comment: The LIMIT clause will always be faster for the starter rows. But this is not true for a bigger set when you are in the middle of your rows, lets say 599,000, 10. Read this article it will clarify it better: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: @zerkms :) no problem

Comment: @JorgeCampos added explain results to the main question.

Comment: So the difference is clearly because of the LIMIT clause. I would suggest more tests without the first limit (0,10), try starting high like: `LIMIT 600000, 10` and see how long it gets

Comment: Also, is your mysql version 5.7?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Well, I don't have that many records for a keyword, but `LIMIT 30000, 10` with JSON_SEARCH takes about 13seconds and `tags LIKE '%Hampden%'` with the same limit takes under 2 seconds. So like @zerkms said, JSON_SEARCH is the bottleneck here. Yes, it is 5.7

Comment: You can Try [Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index) To see what happens. PS. you said in your question that your table "has about 1,000,000 rows" (no mention for keyword specif amount ) which is less then the suggested 600000 :) . I do agree that JSON_EXTRACT is part of the problem since it has to validate the json content which is not  trivial for each row in the set...

Comment: `JSON_SEARCH` must parse each row; this is more costly than `LIKE`, and cannot use an index.